# Is it possible to expose an Owin service?

Tags: rest, server, owin, self-hosting

We have created self-hosted services using OWIN. They are working fine inside the server and we can request and retrieve information using the http://localhost. We use a different port for each service so that we can go and get certain information from http://localhost:8001, other from http://localhost:8015 and so on.

Now, we need to expose the results of one of those self-hosted services to access to it through internet. We'd like to provide a custom address such http://ourpublicinfo.mydomain.com:8001 or using the server ip such http://209.111.145.73:8001.

Is that possible?

How can we implement it?

Our server OS is Windows Server 2012 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OWIN Self-Hosted apps can run on a Windows Service, as a Console process and, with if desired, as part of a more robust Host like IIS.

Since you mention your app is running as a service you're probably missing all the GUI goodies IIS provides. In reality however, IIS works on top of http.sys, just as HttpListener does (which is probably what you're using to self-host your app) [1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437733/Demystify-http-sys-with-HttpSysManager). You just need to do some manual set up yourself:

1. First of all, you need to make a **URL reservation** in order to publish on a nonstandard port.

*Why would you do that?* Quite simply because you're not running under localhost alone anymore on your very own local machine, where you probably are an admin and/or have special privileges/powers.

Since this is a server, and the user used for running the Service might not be an admin (most probably), then you need to give permission to that user to use that URL... and here is where URL reservations come into scene.

You pretty much have to options:

- open up the URL to be used by any user:

  ```
   netsh http add urlacl url=http://209.111.145.73:8001/ user="everyone" listen=yes
  ```
- or open up the URL to be used by the user(s) running the service, e.g.: NETWORK SERVICE:

  ```
   netsh http add urlacl url=http://209.111.145.73:8001/ user="NETWORK SERVICE" listen=yes
  ```

There is a way to make the reservation for several users too, using sddl, user groups, etc... but I'll not get into it (you can look that up).

2. Second of all, you need to open up a hall through your **firewall** (if you don't have one on this day and age, I pity you!)

There are plenty of tutorials on this. You can use a GUI, netsh.exe and what not.

Pretty much all you need to do is make sure you allow incoming connections through that port and that should do the trick.

To make sure the hall is open through and through you can use a tool like http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and insert 209.111.145.73 in the *Remote Address* and 8001 in the *Port Number*.

If for some reason it shows that the port is closed, even after creating an incoming rule in your firewall for it, then you probably have one or more firewalls in between your server and the outside world.

---

With those to elements in place you should be able to access your Self-Hosted Service from the outside.

As for accessing your service through an address like http://ourpublicinfo.mydomain.com:8001, you'll need to create a DNS entry somewhere, most likely on your Domain Registrar for *mydomain.com*, where you could create an **A Record** for your *ourpublicinfo* subdomain pointing to 209.111.145.73.

From this point on, you should be able to access your service through direct IP and Port or through the afore mentioned URL.

Best of luck!

> **Note:**
> If your service will be access from other domains, you might need to make sure you have *CORS (Cross Origen Resourece Sharing)* well defined and working on your service too ;)